# how do i automap an many-to-one relationship using fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapping, many-to-one

i have the following class:

```
public class Worker    
{
 public int WorkerID {get;set;}
 public string Name { get;set;}
}

public class TransferOrder
{
  public int TransferOrderID { get;set;}
  public Worker workerTobeTransfered{get;set;}

}
```

how do i automap this classes in fluent nhibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, after a few googling, i figured out the solution:

this is a many-to-one relation and it is mapped using Reference() Method, and the auto mapping already do that:

```
References<Worker>(m => m.Worker);
```

there is also a great article provide many examples of mapping situations which can be found
[Here](http://blog.vuscode.com/malovicn/archive/2009/11/04/fluent-nhibernate-samples-auto-mapping-part-1-2.aspx).